# SqlException server not found error when connecting to an SQL DB from an Azure Function App

Tags: sql-server, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, whitelist

I have deployed a .NET Core Azure Function App running on the consumption pricing plan which connects, through EF Core, to a MS SQL database hosted by my website provider.

I see the following error reported by App Insights when the database connection is attempted:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A
> connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
> respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond.)
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (10060): A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond.
> ...
> Error Number:10060,State:0,Class:20

I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal) to obtain the function app's `outboundIpAddresses` (using [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) which I also double checked with the Azure CLI).

I passed the list of IP's to the support team at my hosting provider & yet still receive the same error.

I know it's not code related as when I run my function app locally, I can connect fine (my local IP is on the SQL Server allow list).

Why can the Azure function not connect to the database?

This is is a small home project so I can't afford the virtual network NAT gateway route.

Comment: For additional context, I re-deployed to a second region, as a way to check if the hosting company had mistyped an IP anywhere by giving them the new set. Stil the same problem (so it does not look like human error - as was the case with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820683/azure-function-call-other-api-failed-with-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-t) and it does seem that I'm having the same problem as in this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568953/allow-list-ips-for-azure-function-app-on-consumption-tier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> running on the **consumption** pricing plan

**Outbound IP addresses reported by functions running on the Consumption plan are not reliable.**

As per [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#find-outbound-ip-addresses):

> When a function app that runs on the Consumption plan or the Premium plan is scaled, a new range of outbound IP addresses may be assigned. When running on either of these plans, you can't rely on the reported outbound IP addresses to create a definitive allowlist. **To be able to include all potential outbound addresses used during dynamic scaling, you'll need to add the entire data center to your allowlist.**

Instead, provide your hosting provider with the outbound IP addresses for the Azure region(/data center) where your Azure function is hosted in, to cover all possible IPs that your Azure function may be assigned.

The official Azure IP ranges for all regions are in a JSON file available for download [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519).

Firstly, download this file.

Secondly, search for `AzureCloud.[region name]` e.g. `AzureCloud.uknorth` or `AzureCloud.centralfrance` which will bring up the IP addresses for Azure cloud in your specific region.

```json
{
  "name": "AzureCloud.uknorth",
  "id": "AzureCloud.uknorth",
  "properties": {
    "changeNumber": 11,
    "region": "uknorth",
    "regionId": 29,
    "platform": "Azure",
    "systemService": "",
    "addressPrefixes": [
      "13.87.120.0/22",
      ...
      "2603:1027:1:1c0::/59"
    ],
    "networkFeatures": []
  }
}
```

Finally, provide your hosting provider with all the IP addresses listed in the fragment.

**Your Azure function should then be able to consistently connect to your database.**

---

N.B. The list can & will update over time albeit more to add than to change - currently, the last modified date is 26th April 2022 as stated in the details section on the download page.

If anything breaks, ensure to check the page for updates or to guarantee no possible outages, upgrade your pricing plan.

---

Extra thoughts...

As you mention this is for a small project, I'm not sure what Azure pricing is like but I'd host the same project on AWS.

For the function itself, AWS Lambda's [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all&all-free-tier.q=AWS%2BLambda&all-free-tier.q_operator=AND) includes 1M free requests per month (like Azure) & 400,000 GB-seconds of compute time per month which should be plenty.

For the connectivity, you'd need a VPC (free), an Internet Gateway (free + negligible data transfer costs), an Elastic IP address (free) and a managed NAT gateway (roughly $1 a day depending on region).

Oh - and you'd get the added benefit of just having 1 Elastic IP address to provide to your hosting provider, which would always stay the same regardless of what 'pricing plan' you're on.

If anything, I'd also take a look at AWS as a potential option for future projects if anything but that's out of scope :)

Comment: Thanks for that - somehow my eyes had passed over that pink/purple section you quoted. I had downloaded that JSON file actually but wasn't sure why it would be needed when the `outboundIpAddresses` is provided (and also wasn't too sure that my host provider would be keen on adding the 100+ IP's - I guess I may find that out!). Does make me wonder why the `outboundIpAddresses` is provided for consumption plans if it's not reliable mind. It mentions the outbound IP's changing in relation to scaling thought - I wouldn't have thought mine had (fairly basic timer trigger)

Comment: @d219 You’re welcome - yes, 100+ IPs hence my suggestion of AWS also being a possible avenue. I think by scaling it also means everytime the function is stopped and started - not entirely sure how long Azure keeps them running after initial invocation (I’m an AWS guy) but it mostly likely changes everytime the function scales up when you send a request. It’s provided because why not!

Comment: Increasingly looking like the AWS route may be the best bet (which my wife will be happy with as she's an AWS advocate!). I've looked at bit further at the JSON download file info and this text (from Install Instructions at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519 ) sounds nasty "This file is updated weekly. New ranges appearing in the file will not be used in Azure for at least one week. Please download the new json file every week and perform the necessary changes at your site to correctly identify services running in Azure."

Comment: @d219 It’s to make you upgrade your pricing plan - listen to the wife! .NET on AWS is amazing. Give me a shout on LinkedIn if you need any help getting set up quickly or feel free to create any new questions if you hit roadblocks.